# Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1: Arithmetic overflow error converting %ls to data type %ls

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm running this query on SQL Server 2005 and getting error. Could not found the root cause of this issue.

Please help to solve this issue. Is this issue Version specific and coming only with SQL Server 2005 not with 2008?

```
SELECT "AAA1_before_Final13"."AAA1"            AS "level0key",
  "AAA1_before_Final13"."Reporting_Month_Year" AS "levelkey",
  "AAA1_before_Final13"."Reporting_Period"     AS "Reporting_Period",
  "Charge_Type14"."U_INV_CHG_TYPE"             AS "level1key",
  MIN(1)                                       AS "rowCount",
  SUM("AAA1_before_Final13"."Lag_Days")        AS "Lag_Days",
  SUM("AAA1_before_Final13"."Invoice_Count")   AS "Invoice_Count"
FROM
  (SELECT "AAA111"."Division_Name"     AS "Division_Name",
    "AAA111"."Original_FSC"            AS "Original_FSC",
    "AAA111"."FSC_Class"               AS "FSC_Class",
    "AAA111"."FSC_Name"                AS "FSC_Name",
    "AAA111"."Billing_Area_Category"   AS "Billing_Area_Category",
    "AAA111"."Billing_Area"            AS "Billing_Area",
    "dateDim12"."Reporting_Period"     AS "Reporting_Period",
    "dateDim12"."Reporting_Month_Year" AS "Reporting_Month_Year",
    "AAA111"."AAA1"                    AS "AAA1",
    "AAA111"."Lower_Range"             AS "Lower_Range",
    "AAA111"."Upper_Range"             AS "Upper_Range",
    SUM("AAA111"."Lag_Days")           AS "Lag_Days",
    SUM("AAA111"."Inv_Count")          AS "Invoice_Count",
    "AAA111"."GRP"                     AS "GRP"
  FROM
    (SELECT "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Reporting_Period" AS "Reporting_Period",
      "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Reporting_Month_Year"   AS "Reporting_Month_Year",
      "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Reporting_Year"         AS "Reporting_Year",
      "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Deposite_Days"          AS "Deposite_Day",
      "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Deposite_Days"          AS "Deposite_Day1",
      "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Deposite_Days"          AS "Deposite_Day_Grp"
    FROM "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"
    WHERE "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."Date_Dim"."Reporting_Year" = 2013
    AND "Date_Dim"."Day_of_Month"                         = 1
    ) "dateDim12"
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Reporting_Period" AS "Reporting_Period",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Division_Name"          AS "Division_Name",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Class"              AS "FSC_Class",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Original_FSC"           AS "Original_FSC",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Name"               AS "FSC_Name",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area_Category"  AS "Billing_Area_Category",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area"           AS "Billing_Area",
      SUM("AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lag_Days")          AS "Lag_Days",
      SUM("AAA1_Lag_Days"."Inv_Count")         AS "Inv_Count",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lower_Range"            AS "Lower_Range",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Upper_Range"            AS "Upper_Range",
      'AAA1'                                   AS "AAA1",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."GRP"                    AS "GRP"
    FROM
      (SELECT "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Reporting_Period"       AS "Reporting_Period",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Division_Name"                AS "Division_Name",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Original_FSC"                 AS "Original_FSC",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Class"                    AS "FSC_Class",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Name"                     AS "FSC_Name",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area"                 AS "Billing_Area",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area_Category"        AS "Billing_Area_Category",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Reporting_Period_Year"        AS "Reporting_Period_Year",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lag_Days"                     AS "Lag_Days",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Inv_Count"                    AS "Inv_Count",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lower_Range"                  AS "Lower_Range",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Upper_Range"                  AS "Upper_Range",
        "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Group_Num" AS "GRP"
      FROM "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."AAA1_Lag_Days_View" "AAA1_Lag_Days"
      ) "AAA1_Lag_Days"
    WHERE (4                                    = 0
    OR 4                                        = "AAA1_Lag_Days"."GRP")
    AND "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Reporting_Period_Year" = 2013
    AND "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lower_Range"           = 16.49
    GROUP BY "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Reporting_Period",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Division_Name",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Class",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Original_FSC",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."FSC_Name",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area_Category",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Billing_Area",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Lower_Range",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."Upper_Range",
      "AAA1_Lag_Days"."GRP"
    ) "AAA111"
  ON "dateDim12"."Reporting_Period" = "AAA111"."Reporting_Period"
  GROUP BY "AAA111"."Division_Name",
    "AAA111"."Original_FSC",
    "AAA111"."FSC_Class",
    "AAA111"."FSC_Name",
    "AAA111"."Billing_Area_Category",
    "AAA111"."Billing_Area",
    "dateDim12"."Reporting_Period",
    "dateDim12"."Reporting_Month_Year",
    "AAA111"."AAA1",
    "AAA111"."Lower_Range",
    "AAA111"."Upper_Range",
    "AAA111"."GRP"
  ) "AAA1_before_Final13",
  "idxAnalyzer"."dbo"."U_INVOICE_HEADER" "Charge_Type14"
WHERE CAST ("AAA1_before_Final13"."GRP" AS BIGINT) = CAST ("Charge_Type14"."GRP" AS BIGINT)
GROUP BY "AAA1_before_Final13"."AAA1",
  "AAA1_before_Final13"."Reporting_Month_Year",
  "AAA1_before_Final13"."Reporting_Period",
  "Charge_Type14"."U_INV_CHG_TYPE"
```

Comment: I've added the English version of the error message text to the title - because most of us don't have the error numbers memorized - but we'd probably do even better if you can tell us what appeared in the placeholders.

Comment: Can you post the table schemas?

Comment: How can you read this?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: imagine having to **maintain** this code base! <shudder>

Comment: Come on guys, this *must* have be generated by some framework, for who in their right mind would write like this. Aligned ASes look nice, though. I wonder if that's a manual addition or frameworks have grown aesthetic recently.

Comment: The only cast/convert is of GRP from idxAnalyzer.dbo.u_invoice_header and aaa1_lag_days. Without knowing their base data types it's impossible to say whether this is valid or not; also if there are null values in those columns you can get this error too. However, there are a lot of other things which could cause this error also. Just not enough data to give an answer, really.

Comment: Hi Simon, Base datatype of dbo.u_invoice_header.GRP is int and of dbo.AAA1_Lag_Days.Group_Num is smallint.

Comment: Also values can't be null in both these column as NOT NULL constraint is applied on both of them.